# Azure Api Management append api to existing api with arm

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I wonder how you can append a second api to an already registered api in Azure api management via an ARM deploy?

If I use the same value for the name property in my Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis resource. It overwrites the whole api instead of appending it. I don't find a property in the arm reference docs to specify I want to append the api instead of overwriting it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/apis

I want to accomplish the same result via arm, like I am able todo via the Azure portal import menu [image: Imgur] 
This is also described in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually#append-other-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easily not possible at the moment. "Append" logic is implemented in UI, but it does rely only on publicly available ARM calls. You could inspect calls it makes to ARM to append one API to another and try to reproduce it "by hand".

Comment: Are you sure about this? Combining multiple backend services in one logical api endpoint on the frontend looks like a selling point to use the api gateway pattern. Doing it from the Azure portal is nice for demo purposes or pet projects but in an enterprise environment you want to integrate this in the CI/CD pipeline. We use the [apim devops resource kit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit), each project takes the openapi definition from swashbuckle and generates an arm template. Sometimes 2 generated arms should be able to register behind 1 logical api in APIM.

Comment: I'm sure, yes. It's definitely possible with ARM API directly and ARM templates, the problem is that there is nothing right now that would make it easier. What is being done now from UI (and you can clearly see that in browser dev console) is Azure portal loads OpenAPI file and goes through each operation creating operation in APIM, optionally trying to resolve conflicts around duplicate things. And adding a policy for each operation to direct call to an endpoint from OpenAPI file. You can submit a wish here https://aka.ms/apimwish to ask to make it easier, it's definetly a gap in API.